# How do I find out what button was clicked?

Tags: c#

If I have 150 buttons Is it possible to not have to have a individual button_Click Methods.

```
    public Button findClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnClicked = (Some code)
        return btnClicked;
    }
```

Comment: buttons's can have tags to better identify them and the "sender" in this case is likely the button itself.

Comment: Is this windows forms? Web forms, WPF, or what?

Comment: the parameter `sender` is the object which is handling that event. you can cast the object with appropriate type. ie. `(Button)sender`, `(Button)TextBox`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Button btnClicked = (Button)sender;
```

Comment: `(Button)sender` for no RTTI!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
var name = button.Name;
```